# Colorear área bajo la curva

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un problema con mi código, después de hacer las gráficas necesito sombrear el área que esta encerrada entre las dos rectas bajo cada una de las curvas.

```
#Limpiar datos
remove(list=ls())
dev.off()
cat("\014")

par(mfrow= c(1,2))


curve ((x/2),n=10000,lwd=3, from=0, to=2, type = "l", main = "Densidad de Probabilidad de X", xlab="x", ylab="y", col.axis="red",ylim=c(0,1))
abline(v=.5, lwd = 2, col = "red")
abline(v=1, lwd = 2, col = "red")


curve((1/6*x^{-1/3}),n=10000, lwd=3,from=0, to=8, type = "l", main = "Densidad de Probabilidad de Y", xlab="x", ylab="y", col.axis="red",ylim=c(0,.80))
abline(v=.125, lwd = 2, col = "red")
abline(v=1, lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre más rápido es dibujar unos polígonos que representen el área en cuestión. En primer lugar conviene definir las funciones como tales:

```
f1 <- function(x) x/2
f2 <- function(x) (1/6*x^{-1/3})
```

Luego los polígonos se definen indicando los vértices, el primero es bastante sencillo:

```
p1 <- cbind(c(.5, .5, 1, 1),
            c(0, f1(.5), f1(1), 0))

p1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.5 0.00
[2,]  0.5 0.25
[3,]  1.0 0.50
[4,]  1.0 0.00
```

El segundo es un poco más complejo por que habrá que definir un conjunto de vértices para representar la curva, el nivel de detalle que queremos para la curva dependera de cuantos vértices generemos:

```
p2 <- cbind(c(.125, seq(.125, 1, .01), 1),
            c(0, f2(seq(.125, 1, .01)), 0))
```

Con los polígonos definidos simplemente habrá que agregar la función `polygon()`:

```
plot.new()
par(mfrow= c(1,2))

curve (f1,n=10000,lwd=3, from=0, to=2, type = "l", main = "Densidad de Probabilidad de X", xlab="x", ylab="y", col.axis="red",ylim=c(0,1))
abline(v=.5, lwd = 2, col = "red")
abline(v=1, lwd = 2, col = "red")

polygon(p1, 
        col = rgb(.25,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
        border = "blue",
        lwd = 2)

curve(f2,n=10000, lwd=3,from=0, to=8, type = "l", main = "Densidad de Probabilidad de Y", xlab="x", ylab="y", col.axis="red",ylim=c(0,.80))
abline(v=.125, lwd = 2, col = "red")
abline(v=1, lwd = 2, col = "red")

polygon(p2, 
        col = rgb(.25,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
        border = "blue",
        lwd = 2)
```

---

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho.